# Problems with points and apply R for linear discriminant analysis

Tags: r, classification, statistics-bootstrap

I have some coding question, which arise doing some exercises in linear discriminant analysis. We are using the Iris data:

```
## Read in dataset, set seed, load package
Iris <- iris[,-(1:2)]
grIris <- as.integer(iris[,"Species"])
set.seed(16)
library(MASS)

## Read n
n <- nrow(Iris)
```

As you can see, we delte the first and second column of iris. What I want to do is a bootstrap for this data using linear discriminant analysis, here is my code:

```
ind <- replicate(B,sample(seq(1:n),n,replace=TRUE))
```

This generates the indices I want to use. Note `B` is some large number, e.g. 1000. Now I want to use apply, but why does the following code doesn't work?

```
bst.sample <- apply(ind,2,lda(Species~Petal.Length+Petal.Width,data=Iris[ind,]))
```

where Species, Petal.Length etc. are the data from iris. If I use a for loop everything works fine, but of course I would like to implement in this more elegant way.

My second question is about `points`. I also wanted to calculate the estimated means, which I've done by the following code

```
est.lda <- vector("list",B)
est.qda <- vector("list",B)
mu_hat_1 <- mu_hat_2 <- mu_hat_3 <- matrix(0,ncol=B,nrow=2)
for (i in 1:B){
  est.lda[[i]] <- lda(Species~Petal.Length+Petal.Width,data=Iris[ind[,i],])
  mu_hat_1[,i] <- est.lda[[i]]$means[1,]
  mu_hat_2[,i] <- est.lda[[i]]$means[2,]
  mu_hat_3[,i] <- est.lda[[i]]$means[3,]
  est.qda[[i]] <- qda(Species~Petal.Length+Petal.Width,data=Iris[ind[,i],])

}

plot(mu_hat_1[1,],mu_hat_1[2,],pch=4)
points(mu_hat_2[1,],mu_hat_2[2,],pch=4,col=2)
points(mu_hat_3[1,],mu_hat_3[2,],pch=4,col=3)
```

The plot at the end should show three region with the expected mean of the three classes. However just the first plot is shown.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  What are you expecting for an output and what are you getting?

Comment: R is case sensitive, so you refer to iris in the beginning and then define grIris, but then use nrow(Iris) where Iris hasn't been defined.  I would start with that.

Comment: @KenKnoblauch `Iris` is defined at the very top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B <- 10
ind <- replicate(B,sample(seq(1:n),n,replace=TRUE))

#you need to pass a function to apply
bst.sample <- apply(ind,2, 
                function(i) lda(Species~Petal.Length+Petal.Width,data=Iris[i,]))
#extract means
bst.means <- lapply(bst.sample,function(x) x$means)

#bind means into array
library(abind)
bst.means <- do.call(function(...) abind(..., along=3), bst.means)

#you need to make sure that alle points are inside the axis limits
plot(bst.means[1,1,],bst.means[1,2,], 
     xlim=range(bst.means[,1,]), ylim=range(bst.means[,2,]), 
     xlab=dimnames(bst.means)[[2]][1],ylab=dimnames(bst.means)[[2]][2],
     col=1)
points(bst.means[2,1,],bst.means[2,2,], col=2)
points(bst.means[3,1,],bst.means[3,2,], col=3)
legend("topleft", legend=dimnames(bst.means)[[1]], col=1:3, pch=1)
```

[image]

Comment: ah! now I see my mistake. lda is not a function. I thought apply knows that I want to apply lda over all ind. Thanks Roland, so much.

Comment: `lda` is a function. But you didn't pass the function to `apply`, but tried to pass the function's return value.

Comment: You are fast. I just wanted to ask, why lda is not a function. Now I see what was really my mistake. Again, thx. This helps a lot!

Comment: +1 to show appreciation for extended discussion of analysis and data reduction.